# Django does't recognize User as an attribute in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make an edit profile form and I want the default input values to be the current user data. For example in the username field the default value will me the current user username. So I made a Model Form and I tryed this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User_Edit(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'username': Textarea(attrs={'value': model.username })
        }
```

But Django says: AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'username'

Also this is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/home/sebastian/Spartan/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/sebastian/Documents/project-spartan/profiles/models.py", line 8, in <module>
class User_Edit(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/sebastian/Documents/project-spartan/profiles/models.py", line 9, in User_Edit
class Meta:
File "/home/sebastian/Documents/project-spartan/profiles/models.py", line 13, in Meta
'username': Textarea(attrs={'value': model.username })
```

AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'username'

Comment: Well, the _class_ `User` doesn't have a `username` attribute. Why do you need to add an explicit value anyway? It should be handled by the modelform.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't be setting the value of each field in the Meta class. You can initialize a form [from an object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) representing the user you're looking for, so in your view you'd have:

```
#Whatever happens in your view function before you create the form

user_obj = User.objects.get(username = target_username,
    email=target_email)    #Or how ever else you want to get the user in question
form = User_EditForm(instance = user_obj)

#Rest of your view
```

To make your life easier, you might want to look at using the [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) instead, depending on your exact use case.